# Converting a list of tuples to list of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have this below list of tuples in Python:

```
FINAL ZIPPED LIST = [('http://abc123.com/Kit.docx', 'File 1'), ('http://abc123.com/Kit.docx', 'File 2'),...]
```

I want to convert this into a list of lists. Something like this:

```
FINAL ZIPPED LIST = [['http://abc123.com/Kit.docx', 'File 1'], ['http://abc123.com/Kit.docx', 'File 2'],...]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should first look for similar questions before asking directly.

Comment: You told us what you want, but what have you done to try to solve the issue? Nothing on Google for 'Python convert tuple to list'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like:

```
new_list = [list(x) for x in FINAL_ZIPPED_LIST]
```